# Execute @Formula in merged value

Tags: hibernate, merge, formula

*Hi all,*
I faced with a problem that Formula is not executed in merged entity.
So I have Entity with one property marked with @Formula annotation. When I execute select of entity, the annotated property contains a proper value, but after merge returned persisted entity, the property is always null. Is it possible to trigger execution of the Formula after merge?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to call `session.refresh(theEntity)` after merge().

**session.refresh() method to re-populate the entity with latest data available in database.**

Haven't tried it though.